# How to deal with relative NuGet packages paths to facilitate easy pckages dir relocation with NuGet.Config?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We moved NuGet's `packages` folder to some other place and created a `NuGet.Config` file at the `sln`s level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="../.nugetPackages" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

We also have this in few of our `csproj` files:

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\Proj\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.1.7.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\Proj\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.1.7.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\..\Proj\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.1.7.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\..\Proj\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.1.7.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

And this too:

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\PostSharp.4.2.17\tools\PostSharp.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\PostSharp.4.2.17\tools\PostSharp.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsurePostSharpImported" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(PostSharp30Imported)' == ''">
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\PostSharp.4.2.17\tools\PostSharp.targets')" Text="This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://www.postsharp.net/links/nuget-restore." />
    <Error Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\PostSharp.4.2.17\tools\PostSharp.targets')" Text="The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see http://www.postsharp.net/links/nuget-restore." />
</Target>
```

My question is how to deal with such relative `package` paths in the `csproj` files to keep things generic (so we could easily move the `package` folder anytime anywhere)?

Is there maybe some variable we can use like `$NuGetPackagesDir` or something like that?

(We use Vs2015, NuGet 5.3 and TeamCity build server [I don't remember current version..])

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really have a generic path and still use the NuGet tooling within Visual Studio since when you update a package the hint path will be updated by NuGet back to a relative path if you are using a packages.config file.

Whilst you could specify a global packages folder the hint paths will be relative to that path depending on where you put the solution.

The hint path problem goes away when you use a project.json file or have a new .NET Core style project that uses PackageReference elements in the .csproj file. If you are using a packages.config file then your .csproj file will have hint paths pointing to assemblies within the packages folder.

Comment: I don't mind it updates the `HintPath` as long as it takes the path from `NuGet.Config`. If it doesn't, then why does it exist? what problem does that `NuGet.Config` file solve?

Comment: It takes it from the NuGet.Config, as in the path is used, but a relative path will be added to the .csproj file. There was a plan to support an environment variable in the NuGet.Config file but I suspect the .csproj file would not use that variable.

Comment: So I don't understand... the NuGet.Config is useless, as this is the most widespread use case, relative packages folder. What am I missing here?

Comment: The NuGet.Config file is not useless. It allows you to share a packages folder between solutions. It just will not help in your scenario where you have a shared packages folder which is outside your solution directory when you allow the solution directory to have any location.